# What is the right method for making a single page using laravel and jquery or Vue JS

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js

I have a page function.blade.php I want to be a single page, add function display function delete function, and when I add a function it must be displayed directly in the table.
what the right way to do?

```
 <form action="{{ url('addfonction') }}" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <label for="fonction">Fonction: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fonction" placeholder="fonction">
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg" >Ajouter</button>
      </form>
     </div>

     <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover" id="mytable">
      <hr>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i> Fonction</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead> 
      <tbody> 
       @foreach($fonctions as $fonction) 
        <tr>
          <td class="hidden-phone">{{ $fonction->fonction }}</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Vue is very easy to create a Single Page Application. 
In your code when you submit the form the page will reload, right? With **Vue**, you could use `<form submit.prevent="function()">` to prevent the redirect / reload.

I don't really get if your problem is that :P